# lstrip and rstrip not removing in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, strip

I feel like I have a very straightforward piece of code. I have a file name that follows the form of `'stuff_category.csv`'. I'm trying to remove `'stuff_'` and `'.csv'`, so that I will be left with `'category'`, which I need for the next piece of code. `'stuff_'` can be many different things, so I can't use the replace() function. Right now I have

```
filename = "stuff_category.csv"
category = filename.lstrip('_').rstrip('.')
```

But if I try `print(category)`, or even `print(category.lstrip('_'))`, it just returns the original file name. What am I missing?

Comment: You missed reading the documentation about how [`.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) and [`.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) work.

Comment: If you want to extract base name and/or file extension use `os.path.splitext(filename)` which returns ('stuff_category', '.csv').

Comment: @MarkTolonen I didn't "miss" it, I guess I just misunderstood how it works. Everything I saw said when lstrip() is given an argument, it removes everything before that argument.

Comment: I found that 'filename.split('.')[0].split('_')[-1]' produces the result I'm looking for. It's not as pretty as I was hoping for, but it gets the job done.

Comment: @user2954167 The linked official docs give clear examples of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using *`removeprefix`* and *`removesuffix`* (Python 3.9) rather than *lstrip* and *rstrip*:

```py
filename = "stuff_category.csv"
print(filename.removeprefix('stuff_').removesuffix('.csv')) #category
```

Or using *Slicing* with *`startswith`* *`endswith`*  (Python 3.8):

```py
start = "stuff_"
end = ".csv"
if filename.startswith(start):
    filename = filename[len(start):]
if filename.endswith(end):
    filename = filename[:-len(end)]
print(filename) #category
```

Or even use *Slicing* with just *`index`*:

```py
print(filename[filename.index('_')+1:filename.index('.')]) #category
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) for these methods. They don't use the provided character as a delimiter, they remove the characters as if a substring.

```
lstrip(self, chars=None, /)
    Return a copy of the string with leading whitespace removed.
    
    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
```

Try this:

```py
filename = "stuff_category.csv"
category = filename.lstrip('stuff_').rstrip('.csv')
```

Consider using a regular expression or `str.split` instead of `lstrip`/`rstrip` if `"stuff_"` isn't constant.

Comment: Your example isn't really how it works either.  `.lstrip('stuff_')` for example removes all *combinations* of s, t, u, f and _ from the right, so `"stuff_futs_category".lstrip('stfu_')` would return `"category"`.

Comment: Python 3.9 introduces `removeprefix` and `removesuffix` methods that do what everyone always thinks `lstrip` and `rstrip` do before they realize their mistake.

Comment: @MarkTolonen thanks for the correction

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica the `str.removeprefix` and `str.removesuffix` methods are indicated here, and they're easy for OP to implement if not using 3.9

Comment: I wanted to avoid using str.split. Then I have to add a step of finding the right item in the list, and that's a bit bulkier than I wanted. But I suppose if that's the only way, then that's what I have to work with.

Comment: @user2954167, definitely try something other than the strip methods. For reasons mentioned above they will likely produce bugs in this case.